# Vector valued contraction

Tags: functional-analysis, functional-equations, fixed-point-theorems

I am familiar with the [Banach Fixed Point Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed_point_theorem) and I have used it to prove existence and uniqueness of functional equations in Banach spaces like $C(X)$, the space of bounded continuous function $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb R$ with the sup norm $||f||=\sup_{x\in X}|f(x)|$, $X\subset \mathbb R^n$.

I am trying now to show existence and, particularly, uniqueness of the solution to a system of functional equations $F: \mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R^2$ that looks like this:

$\left(\begin{array}{c}
F_{1}\left(x_{1}\right)\\
F_{2}\left(x_{2}\right)
\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}
G_{1}\left[F_{1}\left(\cdot\right),F_{2}\left(\cdot\right)\right]\\
G_{2}\left[F_{1}\left(\cdot\right),F_{2}\left(\cdot\right)\right]
\end{array}\right)$

Where $G_1: \mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R$ and $G_2: \mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R$.

In general, $F_{1}$ and $F_{2}$ in the right hand side are not evaluated only at $x_1$ and $x_2$, so the problem cannot be solved pointwise. All the functions behave nicely and I have solved my problem numerically and it converges smoothly (like a contraction).

I have two questions:

1. Which Banach space is the natural one to use for functions that map into $\mathbb R^2$?
2. Are there easy to check sufficient conditions for my two dimensional system to be a contraction, like [Blackwell's Sufficient Conditions](http://www.google.com/search?aq=0&oq=goo&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=google#hl=en&sugexp=ldymls&pq=google&xhr=t&q=blackwell%27s+sufficient+conditions+for+contraction&cp=48&qe=YmxhY2t3ZWxsJ3Mgc3VmZmljaWVudCBjb25kaXRpb25zIGZvciBjb250cmFjdGlv&qesig=8REFo_qK6pcPB21I85Vz_w&pkc=AFgZ2tmvr_nfiZgU8LtthCfjmVCGZ2ApFnTu0pG0DiWWx-gHc_prt0HYqldsL39iqjjZIlXE0ah3GllmO9QFjZMhu2nzVUtb_A&pf=p&sclient=psy&source=hp&aq=0p&aqi=&aql=&oq=blackwell%27s+sufficient+conditions+for+contractio&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=a316b5cdb3fe9040)?

I have looked into some fixed-point theory books, but I haven't found anything that directly applies to my problem.

Comment: Well, if $E$ is any Banach space, the natural norm on $C(X,E)$ is $\sup_{x \in X} \|f(x)\|_{E}$, where $\|\cdot\|_{E}$ denotes the norm on $E$. Now if $E = \mathbb{R}^2$ I'd probably choose the maximum norm $\left\Vert\begin{pmatrix} x \\y\end{pmatrix}\right\Vert_{\infty} = \max{\{|x|,|y|\}}$, but you can choose your favourite norm on $\mathbb{R}^2$, that is, one which may be better adapted to your problem. What is a bit unclear to me in your question is how your map $G$ is supposed to act on $C(X,\mathbb{R}^2)$.

Comment: @Theo I edited the question clarifying the nature of $G$. In my particular problem it is just an ugly combination of $F_1$ and $F_2$ evaluated at different points. The norm you suggest in my case should be $\left\Vert \left(\begin{array}{c}
F_{1}\left(\cdot\right)\\
F_{2}\left(\cdot\right)
\end{array}\right)\right\Vert =\max\left\{ \sup_{y\in\mathbb{R}}\left\{ F_{1}\left(y\right)\right\} ,\sup_{y\in\mathbb{R}}\left\{ F_{2}\left(y\right)\right\} \right\}$. Is that right?

Comment: No, it's the other way around. A priori, $X$ is an arbitrary (topological or metric space) and the norm I suggest to use is $\left\Vert\begin{pmatrix} F_1(\cdot) \\F_2(\cdot)\end{pmatrix}\right\Vert = \sup_{x \in X} \max{\{|F_1(x)|,|F_2(x)|\}}$. What is $X$ in your question? Is it $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{R}^2$? I guess it's the former, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: @Theo In my case is $\mathbb R$, right. As you argue, using a more general space wouldn't change things. I'll try with your suggestion; I am not very familiar with vector-valued norms.

Comment: I guess $G_1$ and $G_2$ are bounded functions: $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$. This gives a function $G=(G_1,G_2)$. What confuses me a bit is your fixed point equation and your comment afterwards. Writing $F = (F_1, F_2)$, your fixed point equation should become $G \circ F = F$, and your looking for an $F$ satisfying this. Now to apply the fixed point theorem, you should find a closed subset $\mathcal{F}$ of $C(X,\mathbb{R}^2)$ that is preserved by $G$ and $G$ acts contractively. Then you can start with any $H$ in $\mathcal{F}$. Iterating $H \mapsto G \circ H$ gives you the unique fixed point.

Comment: @Theo Sorry if I was confusing. Your last comment states very clearly what I am trying to solve, and that is the way I proceeded numerically. I didn't know which metric to use (other suggestions are welcomed) and I was interested in knowing some result useful to show that $G$ is a contraction.

Comment: In this generality, it seems impossible for me to say anything more. What I did so far, is merely pronouncing some generalities. Can you write down the functions $G_1$ and $G_2$ and with what $H$'s you started in your numerical experiments? Maybe this gives me a clue.

Comment: A simple version looks like $F_1(x_1)=\Phi[\sum_{s=1}^n a_s F_1(y_s)+\sum_{s=1}^n F_2(y_s)]$ and $F_2(x_2)=\Phi[\sum_{s=1}^n F_1(y_s)+\sum_{s=1}^n a_s F_2(y_s)]$, where $\Phi$ denotes the cdf of a normal distribution and $a_s$ are scalars. In this example, $F_1$ is a contraction given $F_2$ and viceversa, but I wanted to be sure about how to make the argument jointly.

Comment: Oy, this looks messy... Okay, and what are the $y_s$'s? How do they depend on $x_1$ and $x_2$?

Comment: I should have written: $F_1(x_1)=\Phi[F_1(x_1) +\sum_{s=1}^n F_1(y_s)+\sum_{s=1}^n F_2(y_s)]$ and $F_2(x_2)=\Phi[F_2(x_2) +\sum_{s=1}^n F_1(y_s)+\sum_{s=1}^n F_2(y_s)]$ In general, the $y_s$ are some points where we have to evaluate the function.

Comment: Sorry if I'm dense: So the $y_s$'s are just $n$ fixed real numbers and do not move at all?

Comment: Yup. Fixed numbers.